# How can I remove a closet shelf & keep it intact?

Tags: shelving, demolition, closet

How do I remove a closet shelf that is flush against the closet wall with just a brace in the middle? The brace is not a problem, but the shelf looks like it's glued in. It has a 2 X 1(maybe) X 72 (closet length). And two small braces on each end about 2 ft in length X maybe 1" wide.

Comment: rubber mallet + a few whacks?

Comment: Remove any screws from the brackets, then I suspect @DA01 has the right idea. Things that have been painted over can often feel glued. Try using a razor blade along any edges where the shelf meets the walls or supporting brackets to prevent the paint from holding it in place.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely nailed from above into braces.

May be glued and/or caulked, so run a utility knife or window razor (single straight edge razor in a holder).

Then, as suggested by DA01 and Jacob S, wack upwards with a rubber mallet or a regular hammer into a block of wood